# How can I get the security token?

Tags: security-token

I'm trying to get the token security token with a profile for integration (custom profile) and with profile admin (view all) and I can not access the option to reset. I try go to "My personal information" -> "Reset My security" but this option not is available
Where can I get it?
Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please select 'My Settings' from your name menu displayed on top of the page at right-side.
[image: My Settings]

Now, on left side panel, click on 'Personal' and then 'Reset My Security Token' from expanded menu. And finally click 'Reset Security Token' button.
[image: Reset Security Token]

If you still don't see this option listed then please refer this Knowledge Article for further help: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000182450&type=1

Comment: Ooo I have "Login IP Ranges". According to that documentation, having Login IP Ranges I can not get the TOKEN. How strange, in other projects I had token and IP Ranges established. Ok, it will have changed. Thank you